# Define value in subItemList

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to change item when get form API like here

```
advs : [];

//get data from api and result like here
advs = { 
    item = {id = 1, CreateDate = "2016-02-02"}, imageUrl = "/image/test.jpg",
    item = {id = 5, CreateDate = "2016-03-02"}, imageUrl = "/image/ref.jpg"
}
```

I want first convert date to Persian date then show it.
Then I want to change this like here

```
this.advs.item.CreateDate = //convertor
```

The error is

```
item does not exist on type any[]
```

and when I want to change to define advs like here

```
advs : { item: any[], url: string }
```

Then error is

```
CreateDate does not exist on type any[]
```

Comment: `this.advs.item['CreateDate']`.

Comment: not work, Cannot set property 'CreateDate' of undefined

Comment: simple.. your item is undefined

Comment: item is exist but i can not change value